# Rails 5.2 credentials when cloning repo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I've been using the new credential system added to 5.2, but I run into an issue with recreating the master.key on a repo clone.

1. nano /config/master.key
2. copy and paste from password manager

In doing so I receive the following error:

```
/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/bundler/gems/rails-bb2fddc3b839/activesupport/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:205:in `rescue in _decrypt': ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage (ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage)
```

If I copy the actual file it works just fine, but that's more of a hassle for me.

Comment: I have the same problem.